# What is the meaning of “#nnnnnnnnnnnn” in GNOME terminal configuration file?

Tags: configuration, colors, parameter

The file `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
        <entry name="use_theme_colors" mtime="1517920383" type="bool" value="false"/>
        <entry name="font" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>Monospace 14</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="use_system_font" mtime="1517920383" type="bool" value="false"/>
        <entry name="default_size_rows" mtime="1517920383" type="int" value="100"/>
        <entry name="default_size_columns" mtime="1517920383" type="int" value="150"/>
        <entry name="use_custom_default_size" mtime="1517920383" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <entry name="palette" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>#2E2E34343636:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:#757550507B7B:#060698209A9A:#D3D3D7D7CFCF:#555557575353:#EFEF29292929:#8A8AE2E23434:#FCFCE9E94F4F:#72729F9FCFCF:#ADAD7F7FA8A8:#3434E2E2E2E2:#EEEEEEEEECEC</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="alternate_screen_scroll" mtime="1517920383" type="bool" value="true"/>
        <entry name="background_color" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>#FDFDF6F6F3F3</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="visible_name" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>Default</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="bold_color" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>#000000000000</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="foreground_color" mtime="1517920383" type="string">
                <stringvalue>#B5B589890F0F</stringvalue>
        </entry>
</gconf>
```

I'm curious about these `stringvalue` entries:

- `palette`
  value=`#2E2E34343636:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:…`
  *(Colon-separated string of 16 of these 12-character values)*
- `background_color`
  value=`#FDFDF6F6F3F3`
- `bold_color`
  value=`#000000000000`
- `foreground_color`
  value=`#B5B589890F0F`

Are these values colors? 
If so, why are there 12 bytes instead of the usual six?

Comment: Because they're 48-bit colors.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams please, restate you comment as an answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there any website to pick this type of color code like https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp